# 404 for requests when running wordpress out of subdirectory

Tags: wordpress, http-status-code-404, gtmetrix

While working on the loading speeds of my wordpress projects I stumbled across requests named as "GET wp" by GTMetrix and "/wp/" by google devconsole, which leads to a 404. The resource is requested several times whilew loading the index page and always leads to a 404.

Searching google and here brought nothing enlightening so far. Of course I can provide more insight in the requests/responses if needed, but my best guess so far is that this is due to the specific installation of this wordpress project, which I migrated from the subdirectory /wp/wordpress/ to /wp/ after a bad  automatic installation by the hoster (never did it again :)).

https://selbstwaerts.de/

Any hints are very much appreciated.

Comment: I think, you migrate website in wrong way. can you in detaile explain, how you did it?

Comment: In a way you are right, thanks for your input. The migration itself was successful, but in the aftermath the emptied index.php in the subdir was populated with the wp code again.

Answer (score 0):

After checking the source files for your website, I have come to this conclusion:

Your actual WordPress files reside in a subdirectory named "wp" whereas it's serving content as the docroot directory. Due to the same reason, the wp-config file is accessible from wp subdirectory but not root.

You can fix this by moving your WordPress files to the main directory.

Answer (score 0):

The wordpress installation was cleanly moved from the subdirectory /wp/wordpress/ to /wp/. The remaining index.php in the /wp/ folder was emptied and left with the lonely comment, as it is best practice.

Nevertheless either wordpress itself or some plugin revived this index.php and filled it with the basic instructions to run wp, so that several requests while loading wordpress resulted in 404-errors, although this was obviously internally corrected and not noticeable on the page front.

Cleaning up this index.php again was the solution, I will keep an eye on further changes to this file.